# Android xhdpi icons

Tags: android

Is there a published size for xhdpi application icons? Or do we just use the hdpi ones at 72x72?

Answer (score 12):

The [supporting multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) page contains this image:

[image]

the image shows that every assets for xhdpi has two times the size of a mdpi asset.

Also Hackbod gave an answer in the [Google Groups](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.handhelds.android.devel/155235)

> XHDPI_SIZE = (HDPI_SIZE) * (XHDPI_DENSITITY / HDPI_DENSITY)
>   In other words, 2x the mdpi size.
>   Launcher Icon : 96x96